# wxWidgets resizable pane

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Is there any equivalent in wxWidgets of a resizable pane in gtk like in the following: http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkPaned.html or is this not possible in wxWidgets without rolling  your own implementation of it.

Comment: A better place to ask would be the WxWidgets forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICS this is [wxSplitterWindow](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_splitter_window.html).

Comment: Is there some sort of limit on adding this in a box sizer? It will not properly add itself to a vertical box is simply floats in the top left of the frame.

Comment: No, any window can be put in a sizer. You must have some other mistake somewhere.